# how to create a collection of routes across packages in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm coding an ap in laravel 4 that will use several packages (eg page/blog/gallery) and in the admin area I want to have a list to the base admin route for each package eg:

```
Edit CMS (goes to admin/page/)
Edit Blog (goes to admin/blog)
Edit Gallery (goes to admin/gallery)
```

I can't work out how to do this, I thought if I could set something in the register method of each packages service provider, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that, and then how to pull it out in blade.

Answer (score 0):

in you view files:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('admin/page/')}}">Edit CMS</a>
```